# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int). while implementing wide and deep network

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to implement wide and deep neural network using keras, I am using keras official code implementation but I want to pass numpy array as a dataset  instead of  csv file.

Code:
def get_dataset_from_csv(csv_file_path, batch_size, shuffle=False):

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    csv_file_path,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    column_names=CSV_HEADER,
    column_defaults=COLUMN_DEFAULTS,
    label_name=TARGET_FEATURE_NAME,
    num_epochs=1,
    header=True,
    shuffle=shuffle,
)
return dataset.cache()
```

used below link for code implementation: https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/wide_deep_cross_networks/

Above function is used to generate cache dataset using tensorflow function "make_csv_dataset" but **I want to pass numpy array as dataset directly.**
what could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Keras doesn't support int type so you need to cast them to float. Simple way is changing the type to float after you load your data as numpy array:

```
x = x.astype('float32')
```